# opening a react native app when pressing a push notification (android)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I'm using [react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) to receive and display push notifications in a react native app, but I'm encountering some problems.

Specific for android: when the app is killed or in background mode, and I receive a push notification, tapping the push notification doesn't open the app.

I'm sending push notifications through AWS SNS with the following payload:

```
{
  default: "hello world",
  GCM: {
    notification: {
      title: "This is the title",
      body: "This is the body"
    }
  }
}
```

The notification is displayed correctly when the app is in background mode/closed, and when the app is opened I get the notification payload through `Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground`.

The problem is, as said before: tapping the notification doesn't open the app.

Do I need something else added in my AndroidManifest.xml? This is my manifest so far:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/BootTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_stat_notification" />
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="my_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance!